# Error in grouping by month and calculating the average temperature of each month

Tags: python, pandas

I am preparing data in a python project using jupyter, pandas, and scikit-learn. I am trying to add monthly averages of the maximum temperature in the form of a new column. But whenever I use this function:

```
# Group by month in the temperature max column and use the previous rows to calculate the means
core_weather["monthly_avg"] = core_weather["temp_max"].groupby(core_weather.index.month).apply(lambda x: x.expanding(1).mean())
```

I get two errors:

```
ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer
```

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Do I need to change something in the code creating monthly-avg?

Here is a sample of my current table:

```
DATE       precip   snow    snow_depth  temp_max    temp_min    target  month_max                           
1969-06-01  0.00    0.0 0.0 90  72  85.0    NaN

1969-06-02  0.18    0.0 0.0 85  62  80.0    NaN

1969-06-03  0.06    0.0 0.0 80  60  66.0    NaN

1969-06-04  1.27    0.0 0.0 66  60  78.0    NaN

1969-06-05  0.00    0.0 0.0 78  56  86.0    NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...

2023-09-15  0.02    0.0 0.0 91  71  92.0    100.600000

2023-09-16  0.04    0.0 0.0 92  73  95.0    100.166667

2023-09-17  0.00    0.0 0.0 95  73  94.0    99.900000

2023-09-18  0.00    0.0 0.0 94  69  93.0    99.600000

2023-09-19  0.00    0.0 0.0 93  68  93.0    99.100000
```

I have tried changing the data type of the index from datetime to timedelta in this code:

```
core_weather.index = pd.to_datetime(core_weather.index)
```

I was expecting a new column to be created, but I got a different error saying Only leading negatives allowed.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your table?

Comment: Okay. I just shared a table in the form of link. @Burrito

Comment: @ShadowKnight Please don't post link to images. [edit] your question and put there small sample data + expected output in text form (so we can copy-paste it)

Comment: your example is not reproducible https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use method `.transform()` instead of `.apply()`

```
core_weather['monthly_avg'] = core_weather.temp_max.groupby(core_weather.index.month).transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the monthly avg column with a groupby mean and a join:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'max_temp': [10, 12, 15, 13]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-17', '2023-01-18', '2023-02-18', '2023-02-19']))

monthly_avg = df.max_temp.groupby(df.index.month).mean().to_frame().rename(columns={'max_temp': 'monthly_avg'})

df.set_index(df.index.month).join(monthly_avg)
```